# How to make formula from a vector

Tags: r, formula

I need a way to create formula from a string vector.

For example, I have vector:

```
a<-c("var1", "var2", "var3")
```

Now I need to make formula from that vector. Corresponding formula for vector above should look like:

```
~var1 + var2 + var3
```

So, the result formula should begin with `~` and after should go variable names separate by `+`. Each variable name correspond to each cell of the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is `paste` and using `formula`

```
as.formula(paste0("~ ", paste(a, collapse=" + ")))
#~var1 + var2 + var3
```

Or an easier option is `reformulate` without specifying the `response` which would be `NULL` by default`

```
reformulate(a)
#~var1 + var2 + var3
```